# How do I retrieve an object from the GTM dataLayer

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I have an image tag that I need to populate with the information from the eCommerce purchase. I need the individual items that are stored as a 'product' object in the Tagmanager datalayer. As per Google Analytics Enhanced Ecommerce tracking:

```
  dataLayer.push({
    'ecommerce': {
      'purchase': {
        'actionField': {
          'id': 'T12345',                         // Transaction ID. Required for purchases and refunds.
          'affiliation': 'Online Store',
          'revenue': '35.43',                     // Total transaction value (incl. tax and shipping)
          'tax':'4.90',
          'shipping': '5.99',
          'coupon': 'SUMMER_SALE'
        },
        'products': [{                            // List of productFieldObjects.
          'name': 'Triblend Android T-Shirt',     // Name or ID is required.
          'id': '12345',
          'price': '15.25',
          'brand': 'Google',
          'category': 'Apparel',
          'variant': 'Gray',
          'quantity': 1,
          'coupon': ''                            // Optional fields may be omitted or set to empty string.
         },
         {
          'name': 'Donut Friday Scented T-Shirt',
          'id': '67890',
          'price': '33.75',
          'brand': 'Google',
          'category': 'Apparel',
          'variant': 'Black',
          'quantity': 1
         }]
      }
    }
  });
```

So now I need to iterate through the products to build the image URL like:

```
http://some-domain.com/?p1=12345&v1=15.25&p2=67890&v2=33.75...
```

Because the data is already in the dataLayer, I should be able to write some JavaScript to retrieve the product object, iterate over it's elements and create the string part that I need to append to the image URL. Makes sense, no?

BUT: I do not know how to retrieve the product element within a tag. I tried creating the product object as a variable in tag manager, but that doesn't seem to work. I tried accessing it via:

> google_tag_manager["GTM-uniqueid"].dataLayer.get('ecommerce').purchase.products

but again that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to include an event in the dataLayer, for example:

```
dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'ecomm event',
    'ecommerce': {
      'purchase': {
        'actionField': {
          'id': 'T12345',                         // Transaction ID. Required for purchases and refunds.
          // .... your original stuff
         }]
      }
    }
  });
```

In GTM, you would create a variable that would loop through that dataLayer when that event happens, and return the product names, something like this (you can tidy it up a bit):

```
function(){
    var dl = {{DL - Ecomm products}};
    var prodNames = '';
    for (var i=0; i<dl.length; i++){
        prodNames += dl[i].name + '|';
    }
    return prodNames;
}
```

where `{{DL - Ecomm products}}` is a dataLayer variable with a value of `ecommerce.purchase.products`.

Answer (score 0):

For those that struggle with the same:

1. Create a DL Variable as ecommerce.purchase.products
2. Create a Custom JS Variable in GTM as:

> ```
> function() {
> var prods = {{DL - products}};
> var src = "http://YOUR URL/?a=1"; 
> var len = prods.length;
> for (i=0; i < len; i++) {
> var b = i+1;
> src = src + "&ITEM" + b + "=" + prods[i].id + "&AMT" + b + "=" + prods[i].price + "&QTY" + b + "=" + prods[i].quantity;
> }
> src = src + "&CURRENCY=GBP";
> return src;
> }
> ```

3. Traffic the image tag as your Custom JavaScript Variable.

Done

PS: Sorry about the bad formatting.